# multidimensional arrays in awk

Tags: multidimensional-array, awk, gawk

I tried creating a pseudo-multidimensional array in awk.

```
# Calculate cumulative context score

BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }

{
        a[$2+FS+$7,$3]+=$6
}

END { for (i,j) in a
        { print i,j,a[i,j] }

}
```

Output:

```
awk: ccstscan.awk:9: END { for (i,j) in a
awk: ccstscan.awk:9:             ^ syntax error
```

this is what is mentioned in GNU awk manual:

> To test whether a particular index sequence exists in a
>   multidimensional array, use the same operator (in) that is used for
>   single dimensional arrays. Write the whole sequence of indices in
>   parentheses, separated by commas, as the left operand:
>
> ```
>  (subscript1, subscript2, ...) in array
> ```

i tried modifying the script to create a true-multi dimensional array:

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }

{
    a[$2+FS+$7][$3]+=$6
}

END { for i in a
    {
     for j in a[i]
        { print i,j,a[i][j]
        }

    }
}
```

i ran it with gawk. it also gave an error:

```
gawk: ccstscan.awk:6:   a[$2+FS+$7][$3]+=$6
gawk: ccstscan.awk:6:              ^ syntax error
gawk: ccstscan.awk:9: END { for i in a
gawk: ccstscan.awk:9:           ^ syntax error
gawk: ccstscan.awk:11:   for j in a[i]
gawk: ccstscan.awk:11:       ^ syntax error
gawk: ccstscan.awk:11:   for j in a[i]
gawk: ccstscan.awk:11:             ^ syntax error
gawk: ccstscan.awk:12:          { print i,j,a[i][j]
gawk: ccstscan.awk:12:                          ^ syntax error
```

what is the correct format to make and scan multi-dimensional-associative arrays

Comment: the loop is missing ( and ), it's `for (i in a)`, not `for i in a`. Also, your probably getting the first syntax error about the array indices because you're using an older gawk, true multi-dimensional arrays are a fairly recent addition.

Comment: I would add a link of arrays of arrays in gawk4 http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using the simulated multi-dimensional arrays, your loop would need to be like this:

```
  END { 
    for (ij in a) {
      split(ij,indices,SUBSEP);
      i=indices[1];
      j=indices[2];
      print i,j,a[ij]
    }
  }
```

The `(i,j) in a` syntax only works for testing whether a particular index is in the array.  It doesn't work for for-loops, despite the for-loop allowing a similar syntax.

For the true multi-dimensional arrays (arrays of arrays), you can write it like this:

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }

{ a[$2+FS+$7][$3]+=$6 }

END { 
  for (i in a) {
    for (j in a[i]) { 
      print i,j,a[i][j]
    }
  }
}
```

However, arrays of arrays was only added in gawk 4.0, so your version of gawk may not support it.

Another note: on this line:

```
a[$2+FS+$7,$3]+=$6
```

It seems like you are trying to concatenate $2, FS, and $7, but "+" is for numerical addition, not concatenation.  You would need to write it like this:

```
a[$2 FS $7,$3] += $6
```